# Homography preserving a vertical line

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, plane-geometry

Suppose  $ h : =z\mapsto \dfrac{az+b}{cz+d} $ is an homography of the complex plane preserving a vertical line.

What is the general form of  $ h $? Is  $ c $  necessarily equal to  $ 0 $?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably by "complex plane" you really mean the Riemann sphere, and "vertical line" includes the point at $\infty$.   Then besides a suitable linear function, you could take an inversion about a point on the line.